# delete qwidget from layout QT

Tags: qt, layout, qwidget

I have a qwidget (we'll call it qwidget1) inside of a layout of an other qwidget (we'll call it qwidget2), I want to delete everything that is in the layout of qwidget2: I would like to clear the layout so there's nothing in it anymore .. 
what I can do so far is remove completely the qwidget2 by doing:

```
void QCell::deleteMyChildren(){
   delete this;
}
```

but it removes the qwidget2 itself.. that's not what I want.
Please help me remove the items that are inside the layout.

Comment: Just to clarify, because I'm having a similar problem, is qwidget2 represented by QCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just loop inside the items in the layout and remove item from layout, then delete item :

```
void QCell::deleteMyChildren() {
    while (count() > 0) {
        QLayoutItem * item = takeAt(0);
        delete item;
    }
}
```