# Qt - Clear all widgets from inside a QWidget's layout

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I have a `QWidget` in a dialog. Over the course of the program running, several `QCheckBox *` objects are added to the layout like this:

```
QCheckBox *c = new QCheckBox("Checkbox text");
ui->myWidget->layout()->addWidget(c);
```

This works fine for all the checkboxes. However, I also have a `QPushButton` called "clear" in my dialog, which when it is pressed should empty everything out of myWidget, leaving it blank like it was before any of the `QCheckboxes` were added. I've been looking around online and in the docs but I am having trouble finding a way to do this. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14585018/delete-qwidget-from-layout-qt) question which I thought was similar to my problem, and tried their solution like this:

```
void myClass::on_clear_clicked()
{
  while(ui->myWidget->layout()->count() > 0)
  {
    QLayoutItem *item = ui->myWidget->layout()->takeAt(0);
    delete item;
  }
}
```

This however did not seem to do anything. It's worth noting that I'm not sure if this is translated from his answer correctly; it was a bit unclear how the function given should be implemented, so I made my best educated guess. If anyone knows what I can change in the above to make it work (or just a different way that would work), it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The wonderful thing about layouts is that they handle a deletion of a widget automatically. So all you really need is to iterate over the widgets and you're done. Since you want to wipe out all children of a given widget, simply do:

```
for (auto widget: ui->myWidget::findChildren<QWidget*>
                                            ({}, Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly))
  delete widget;
```

No need to worry about layouts at all. This works whether the children were managed by a layout or not.

If you want to be really correct, you would need to ignore the widgets that are child widgets but are stand-alone windows. This would be the case if this was in general-purpose
library code:

```
for (auto widget: ui->myWidget::findChildren<QWidget*>
                                            ({}, Qt::FindDirectChildrenOnly)) 
  if (! widget->windowFlags() & Qt::Window) delete widget;
```

Alternatively, if you only want to delete the children managed by a given layout and its sublayouts:

```
void clearWidgets(QLayout * layout) {
   if (! layout)
      return;
   while (auto item = layout->takeAt(0)) {
      delete item->widget();
      clearWidgets(item->layout());
   }
}
```

Comment: The clearWidgets recursive function was the only way I found to be able to delete nested layouts / widgets that were created programmatically. Not having a UI handle to things makes things hard, but the above function was the secret sauce I needed!

Answer (score 14):

You can try this:

```
    while ( QLayoutItem* item = ui->myWidget->layout()->takeAt( 0 ) )
    {
        Q_ASSERT( ! item->layout() ); // otherwise the layout will leak
        delete item->widget();
        delete item;
    }
```

Comment: ...sorry, I thought this was working, but it actually wasn't :/ thanks though

Comment: item->widget() returns 0 if the layout item is a spacer or a child layout. This will crash

Comment: This will work but you have to check if `item->widget()` is valid and also it's preferred to call the object's [`deleteLater`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater) as opposed to just deleting it. Just patch that line with `if (auto widget = item->widget()) widget->deleteLater();`

Comment: @iKlsR Neither is true: `delete` has defined behavior when passed a null pointer - it does nothing. It's fine to delete widgets whenever, unless this code is within a slot invoked from the widget *and* it uses the widget context (i.e. `this`).

Comment: This code would be slightly more resilient by adding `Q_ASSERT(sender() != item->widget() || ! sender())` - this will avoid hard to debug problems due to deleting a sender widget. It's much easier to fail hard in such a case. It'll have no performance impact in release builds.

Comment: @KubaOber Not disagreeing, can't remember where I used this but what I do remember is qt throwing exceptions when calling delete, I can also recall reading that to defer as above from the docs so maybe it was some weird use case where the widget was in use.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you have a widget hierarchy consisting of cascaded layouts containing widgets then you should better go for the following.

Step 1: Delete all widgets

```
    QList< QWidget* > children;
    do
    {
       children = MYTOPWIDGET->findChildren< QWidget* >();
       if ( children.count() == 0 )
           break;
       delete children.at( 0 );
    }
    while ( true );
```

Step 2: Delete all layouts

```
    if ( MYTOPWIDGET->layout() )
    {
        QLayoutItem* p_item;
        while ( ( p_item = MYTOPWIDGET->layout()->takeAt( 0 ) ) != nullptr )
            delete p_item;
        delete MYTOPWIDGET->layout();
    }
```

After step 2 your MYTOPWIDGET should be clean.

Answer (score 0):

**PySide2 Solution:**

```py
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


def clearLayout(layout: QtWidgets.QLayout):
    for i in reversed(range(layout.count())):
        item = layout.itemAt(i)
        if isinstance(item, QtWidgets.QLayout):
            clearLayout(item)
        elif item.widget():
            item.widget().setParent(None)
        else:
            layout.removeItem(item)
```